# EditText inside a TextVIew?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, textview

I am making a Mad Libs game of sorts for practice, and so I will have things like EditTexts so the user can input data.

However right now the only way I can get this to sort of work is if I use a horizontal LinearLayout and then do something like a TextView followed by an EditText followed by another TextView, but then if the user enters something long in the EditText, the text does not "wrap nicely" but rather it squishes the rightmost TextView. This is to be expected, but it is not my end-desired behavior.

Is there a better way to put EditTexts inside of TextViews?

Comment: I believe you mean between instead of inside

Comment: Sort of. I sort of do mean inside -- as if the entire thing was a TextView (since it auto-wraps) but part of it is an EditText. Similar to how you can make part of a text clickable by using SpannableStrings and such.

Comment: Add `android:singleline="true"` so the EditText doesnt expand in height  and then add max letters with `android:ems="maximum letters"` or set the width in dp

Comment: The problem is that then nothing wraps -- all entries are fixed in position

Comment: What is your desired behavior, exactly?

Comment: Basically like having a multi-line TextView except with certain spots being EditTexts

Answer (score 0):

Just have one TextView and then you can use a `ClickableSpan`and even add multiple ClickableSpan(s) to a given TextView. This gives you the effect of multi-line TextView with certain spots acting like an EditText.

> If an object of this type is attached to the text of a TextView with a
>   movement method of LinkMovementMethod, the affected spans of text can
>   be selected. If clicked, the onClick(View) method will be called.

```
    SpannableString madLibString = new SpannableString("Our school cafeteria has really adjective food");
    ClickableSpan clickableSpan = new ClickableSpan() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View textView) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "The text 'adjective' has been clicked. Do something.",
                           Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
            super.updateDrawState(ds);
            // NOTE: set styling here to give UI feedback that this is text that can be clicked and edited. 
            ds.setColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_red_dark));
        }
    };
    madLibString.setSpan(clickableSpan, 32, 41, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    textView.setText(madLibString);
    textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```